# How to remove the tag with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to remove  `<br>` an item with Jquery the item going after class`<class="item">`?
I use  `$(".item > br").remove();`  but its not work

Comment: Can you provide the html snippet

Comment: without html,perhaps  try `.item + br`

Comment: $(".item").next("br").remove(); maybe ?

Comment: Is your jQuery wrapped in a `ready` function? Are you actually including jQuery on your page? Anything could be wrong and we can only guess with no html and js code provided to us.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0k7xuuk7/1/ seems to do what you're after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The css selector `>` denotes an immediate child. If you want a sibling (they have the same parent) immediately following the item, you can use the `+` selector. You can find other useful selectors in the [W3C specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors). Your could should therefore look like `$(".item + br").remove();` assuming your html looks something like

```
<div class="item"></div>
<br />
```